# Android Fragment transition exit animation played above enter animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I'm implementing Fragment transition animations.

My `exit` animation is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:ordering="together">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.95"
        android:duration="300"/>

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.95"
        android:duration="300"/>

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="10dp"
        android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

`enter` animation is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:valueFrom="1280"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:duration="400"/>
```

Transaction is created like this:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(enter, exit, popEnter, popExit)
            .replace(CONTENT_CONTAINER_ID, newFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

At normal animation speed the unwanted effect is almost invisible due to short animation duration, but, when you slow them down you can clearly see, that `z-order` is wrong.

Entering fragment animation is below exit fragment animation. Is there a workaround to remedy that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005961/fragmenttransaction-animation-to-slide-in-over-top This solution is works for me.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could try the following approach as a work around.

```
fragmentTr.setCustomAnimations(enter, exit);
fragmentTr.hide(currentFragment);
fragmentTr.add(containerId, newFragment, "aTag");
fragmentTr.show(newFragment);
fragmentTr.commit();
```

Do not use replace(). I tried the above approach, and it worked.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, this kind of works, but my navigation is kind of tricky, with custom backstack and this breaks it...

Comment: Note to others: Order is also important. I had setCustomAnimations after show... not a good idae

Answer (score 2):

This is probably already outdated, but I just faced the same problem. I solved it by defining two content areas in my XML, like:

```
<FrameLayout>
   <FrameLayout id="@+id/oldFragment" />
   <FrameLayout id="@+id/newFragment" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I would load the first fragment to `oldFragment` and my transaction looks like this:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .remove(old_frag)
        .add(R.id.newFragment, new_frag)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too old, but I have the same problem with android jetpack.

This answer for android jetpack and navigation graph

1. Set animations in navigation.xml

   ```
   <fragment
   android:id="@+id/specifyAmountFragment"
   android:name="com.example.buybuddy.buybuddy.SpecifyAmountFragment"
   android:label="fragment_specify_amount"
   tools:layout="@layout/fragment_specify_amount">
   <action
       android:id="@+id/confirmationAction"
       app:destination="@id/confirmationFragment"
       app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
       app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
       app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
       app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
   ```
2. Add animation resources

slide_in_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<setxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0" ndroid:duration="200"/>
</set>
```

slide_out_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p" android:duration="200"/>
</set>
```

slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="200"/>
</set>
```

slide_out_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p" android:duration="200"/>
</set>
```

[Other useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711666/activity-navigation-custom-animation-with-popenter-and-popexit-like-fragments)
[More details at android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions)

Other example animations:

- https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-2/data/res/anim/slide_in_left.xml.shtml
- https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-2/data/res/anim/slide_out_left.xml.shtml
- https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-2/data/res/anim/slide_in_right.xml.shtml
- https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-2/data/res/anim/slide_out_right.xml.shtml

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me, to add this line to the Animation

```
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
```