# Activity navigation: custom animation with popEnter and popExit like fragments

Tags: android-activity, navigation, android-animation, onbackpressed

Changing activities with an animation is possible using the code below:

```java
Bundle animation = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(App.getContext(), R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left).toBundle();
startActivity(intent, animation);
```

For fragments you can do something similar on FragmentTransaction:

```java
// ...
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
// ...
```

This works!
But I'd like to have an animation when pressing back (pop from backstack).
For fragments you simply add 2 anim resources (popEnter & popExit):

```java
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right);
```

How can I create the same 'back-animation' for activities?

Comment: I used this code: `overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);` You can see these examples in [GmailAnimation](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/GmailAnimation) or [LopeAnimations](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/LopeAnimations). Also you can see more in this [Blog](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/gmail-overriding-pending-transition/#sthash.CEhJwJLg.dpbs).

Comment: I've answerred my ow question with that same example, but extended it a little ;-)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've found a different though simple approach that seems to work quite well. Animations for activities can also be performed using *overridePendingTransition*, so when the activity finishes you'll simply use that method.

It would be most effective to implement these overrides in a BaseActivity, which is extended by all activities in your project. Now all your activities will automatically include an exit animation and an animation when starting new activities:

```java
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        onLeaveThisActivity();
    }

    protected void onLeaveThisActivity() {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right);
    }

    // It's cleaner to animate the start of new activities the same way.
    // Override startActivity(), and call *overridePendingTransition*
    // right after the super, so every single activity transaction will be animated:

    @Override
    public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
        super.startActivity(intent);
        onStartNewActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void startActivity(Intent intent, Bundle options) {
        super.startActivity(intent, options);
        onStartNewActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
        onStartNewActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options) {
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode, options);
        onStartNewActivity();
    }

    protected void onStartNewActivity() {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
    }
}
```

To round things up, I'll include the 4 anim resources:

**enter_from_right**

```xml
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p"/>
```

**exit_to_left**

```xml
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p"/>
```

**enter_from_left**

```xml
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p"/>
```

**exit_to_right**

```xml
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="100%p"/>
```

ps. You'd probably like to exclude the exit-animation in your starting / main activity ;-)

```java
public class MainMenuActivity extends BaseActivity {
    ....
    @Override
    protected void onLeaveThisActivity() {
        // Don't use an exit animation when leaving the main activity!
    }
}
```

***EDIT Oct 24 2019:***

When navigating from one activity to the next, AND finishing the current activity in the process, take note that `finish()` should be called BEFORE the navigation implementation. If this is done in the wrong order, `onLeaveThisActivity` will be called AFTER `onStartNewActivity`, resulting in the wrong animation.

Comment: Nice approach. I would update the answer to override startActivityForResult methods as well.

Comment: Great suggestion ikarhun, I'll try it out and update my code soon!

Comment: Nice solution. Only problem is that on a device that on my Samsung s6 that has this transition build in, it takes about twice as long to perform this animation compared to devices that don't have it. I created a post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735395/activity-navigation-translation-animation-not-working-correctly-on-samsung-s6

Comment: @ikarhun when I was debugging activity transitions I found that when `startActivityForResult` is called, shortly afterwards `startActivity` is called too, so possibly the override isn't required. However, I'm not sure if this is always the case, and overriding it several times doesn't hurt