# Activity Navigation Translation Animation not working correctly on Samsung (s6)

Tags: android, android-animation, samsung-mobile, android-transitions

The Samsung s6 has a nice transition between activities and it's similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41025993/3396396):

So I decided to add this activity transition animation to my project and set duration to 600ms. Problem only is that somehow on the Samsung device the transition is taking way longer (about 2x as long). Anyone know how to solve this issue??