# FragmentTransaction animation - show enter fragment above exit fragment

Tags: java, android, animation, android-fragments

When you use are examined animation shift fragments (outgoing fragment has a longer duration than the animation comes fragment) faced with the fact that the fragment comes time animation falls under the outgoing fragment - I expected it to be animated over the outgoing fragment. Who knows how to achieve the desired effect it?

first fragment add:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_layout_fragments_container, new FragmentHome(), "home").commit();
```

replace fragment:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.forward_show, R.anim.forward_hide, R.anim.back_show, R.anim.back_hide).replace(R.id.frame_layout_fragments_container, fragment, fragmentName).commit();
```

simple illustrations

now I have:
[image]

what I need:
[image]

Comment: Did you found any answer? I have the same problem and no solution so far...

Comment: @PsyCoder unfortunately unable to quickly and elegantly solve this problem - lack of time had to use multiple containers for one fragment manager - it's certainly a bad practice and dirty work

Comment: How did you solve this problem, please guide more.

Answer (score 0):

something like Zoom-out page transformer?? http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: no, I want to effect it is achieved when the outgoing and incoming fragments move in one direction, but since the incoming fragment has a faster animation, and during the transaction it should be located on top of the outgoing fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try the following approach as a work around.

```
fragmentTr.setCustomAnimations(enter, exit);
fragmentTr.hide(currentFragment);
fragmentTr.add(containerId, newFragment, "aTag");
fragmentTr.show(newFragment);
fragmentTr.commit();
```

Do not use replace(). I tried the above approach, and it worked.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewCompat.setTranslation(getView, 100.f);
```

look for https://stackoverflow.com/a/33816251/6642400

Answer (score 0):

I haved a similar situation. Here is my solution

[Incoming fragment must to be displayed above the outgoing fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76671341/incoming-fragment-must-to-be-displayed-above-the-outgoing-fragment)

Need to hide first current fragment.