# How to show enter fragment above exit fragment while animating.

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, fragmenttransaction

Effect what I want to achieve is to overlay enter (new) fragment above the exit(old) fragment, 
but when I am replacing old fragment by new fragment,the old one just vanishes and new fragment slides up the container, which  is visible (container).

I don't want to animate the old fragment, just keeping old fragment as it is and while it is visible slide up the new fragment above it.

Below is my code :

```
// First time adding fragment i.e. "oldFragemnt"
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, oldFragment, "oldFragemnt");
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();

// while adding "newFragemnt"
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.new_slide_in_up,0,0,R.anim.new_slide_out_down);                                   
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment, "newFragemnt");
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Guide me where I am going wrong. My old fragment is vanishing while the new fragment is sliding up.

Comment: Do you want like [this](http://trickyandroid.com/fragments-translate-animation/) ?

Comment: You have to add the both fragmnet not replace as the name itself tells that it is replacing that's why your old fragment is removing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005961/fragmenttransaction-animation-to-slide-in-over-top This is the right solution!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005961/fragmenttransaction-animation-to-slide-in-over-top This solution is works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replace the replace() with add() to achieve the effect you want. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The new fragment should have an enter animation like this(which you might be doing already):
**enter.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromXDelta="90%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:zAdjustment="top" />
```

The old fragment should stay in the same place like hold.
**hold.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="400"
    android:zAdjustment="bottom" />
```

Comment: still my old fragment is not visible

Comment: And i dont want old fragment to animate, it should be visible in background until new fragment slides up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set **exit** fragment below and **enter** fragment on top then use this
android:elevation="@dimen/_30sdp" in root layout
in your enter fragment